# graphql query with _cast in JSON doesnt work when have '+' on string

Tags: postgresql, graphql, hasura

I am using Hasura GraphQL to query data stored in a JSONB column. I send the key-value pair as search parameters, and the query should return the data that matches the search criteria. However, I have encountered an issue where the query does not return any results when searching for a string that contains the '+' character, even though the string exists in the database. Can you please help me troubleshoot this problem?

```
query myQuery {
  deal_search( where: {
    _or: {
      fields: {
        _cast: {
          String: {
            _iregex: "\"payment_pix_code\": \"00020126360014BR+B1\""
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
) {
    name
}
```

[jsonb in column fields](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jqkwm.png)

I have tried to use other operators, like _contains and _ilike, but anything worked

Answer (score 0):

"+" has meaning in a regex, you need to escape it. Use `\+` in your search expression, i.e.:

```
_iregex: "\"payment_pix_code\": \"00020126360014BR\\+B1\""
```